# Clearing out contenteditable divs from '</br>'

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `contenteditable` element in HTML. And I found no post in Internet related to the problem of clearing out div content from html tags like `<div>` and `</br>` that are inserted as a result of user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (new line).

In other words, if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, user input is posted to the database with extra html tags.

What is the cleanest solution to this issue?

<sub>I am sorry if the question is duplicated, but I failed to found exactly this issue described elsewhere</sub>

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert($('#test').html());
  });
});
```

```css
#test {
  line-height: 1.14;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test' contenteditable='true'></div>
<button>Show me div input</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.html()` method returns the line breaks as `<br>` elements.

You could use the `.text()` method instead.  However, it will remove the line breaks altogether.

If you want to maintain the line breaks, use the `innerText` property:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert($('#test').prop('innerText'));
  });
});
```

```css
#test {
  line-height: 1.14;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test' contenteditable='true'></div>
<button>Show me div input</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.html()` is doing exactly what it says it's doing, getting all the text, plus any html, like `<br>` tags. What you actually want instead is `.text()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert($('#test').text());
  });
});
```

```css
#test {
  line-height: 1.14;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test' contenteditable='true'></div>
<button>Show me div input</button>
```